# Android Alarm RTC fails to create an alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Seem to be having an issue when creating a daily reminder with the AlarmManager, I've seen a few posts on this but I'm still stuck. I successfully got it to work with ELAPSED_REALTIME.

Here is the relevant portion of my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final int PERIOD=5000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    scheduleAlarms(context);
}

public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent reminderServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,reminderServiceIntent, 0);

    // Cancel all alarms before rescheduling them.
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("rx", e.toString());
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And here is my Service:

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {

    public ReminderService() {
        super("ReminderService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v("rx", "I ran!");
    }
}
```

/* Update */
Removed the comment about 3.1 not allowing for exact repeating timers, it is actually 4.4

Comment: i don't quite understand your question. This code does not work, but using `ELAPSED_REALTIME` it does, but then it does not fire every day at 5?

Comment: also, if you read the doc, it says `as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact`, so, not android 3.1, but rather 4.4

Comment: so the question is : what is your targetSdk?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that 3.1 statement, I was referencing another issue and got that version stuck in my head.

Comment: My targetSdk was is indeed 19, but I'm bumping it back to 18 and testing again

Comment: Ok, that seemed to be the issue, I can now see my alarm. If you want to put it in an answer I'll credit you.

Comment: I would be curious in knowing for how long is the alarm delayed if you use targetSdkVersion 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since api 19, for some reason, alarms are no longer exact (whatever that means.)

However, as long as your `targetSdkVersion` is less than 19, the previous behavior is still in place, meaning you can keep on relying on alarms to be exact.